# Python Instagram API - get media by shortcode

Tags: python, instagram-api

I'm attempting to use this api call listed here (I want to get a media object from the instagram url shortcode):

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/?hl=en#get_media_by_shortcode

I've tried using calls like this (`id` is the shortcode)

```
media = instagram_api.media(shortcode=id)
# or
media = instagram_api.media.shortcode(id)
```

I keep getting errors that either say `no parameter found for media id` or `function has no attribute 'shortcode'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to call it with the [Python API](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/705bc2d526dae47a1032e1fee2b7fc0a06d39f00/instagram/models.py#L128) as seen in [this unit test](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/cd9839efc2546f28f87ede2e333334eeee1d4199/tests.py#L105) is:

```
media = instagram_api.media_shortcode(id)
```

The second way won't work because media is a function and `shortcode` isn't a member of the media function. The first doesn't work because the `media` function has no parameter named `shortcode`. The correct function is `media_shortcode(id)`.

Comment: thanks. i didn't see this documented anywhere - is this a normal api convention?

Comment: Yeah, the api does that with `meda/search`, `media/popular` as well as the other endpoints.